# Issue when updating the password with wp_update_user()

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a plugin that has a frontend profile update portion.

If I have this code...

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'    =>   $username,
    'user_email'    =>   $email,
    'user_url'      =>   $website,
    'first_name'    =>   $first_name,
    'last_name'     =>   $last_name,
    'nickname'      =>   $nickname,
    'description'   =>   $bio,
);

global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();
$ID=$current_user->ID;
$ID_array = array('ID' => $ID);
$userdata = $ID_array + $userdata;

$user = wp_update_user( $userdata );
```

...all is good; however, if I also update the password by adding `'user_pass' => $password` thus changing the code to...

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'    =>   $username,
    'user_email'    =>   $email,
    'user_pass'     =>   $password,
    'user_url'      =>   $website,
    'first_name'    =>   $first_name,
    'last_name'     =>   $last_name,
    'nickname'      =>   $nickname,
    'description'   =>   $bio,
);

global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();
$ID=$current_user->ID;
$ID_array = array('ID' => $ID);
$userdata = $ID_array + $userdata;

$user = wp_update_user( $userdata );
```

... I get the following error on the frontend...

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sdglandl/public_html/home/wp-content/themes/converio/header.php:2) in /home/sdglandl/public_html/home/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 942

The same error occurs over and over and over for multiple lines

Comment: try with `userpass` instead of `user_pass`

Comment: @mmm Didn't work

Answer (score 4):

When you update the current user's password the current user's cookies are cleared.  This is similar to an [issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/186326/how-change-wordpress-password-without-logout-need-for-plugin) already discussed.  You'll need to run this code before any HTML is rendered to prevent the headers being already set issue.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'set_current_users_password' );

function set_current_users_password() {
    // Get current logged-in user.
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Change password.
    wp_set_password($new_password, wp_get_current_user()->ID);

    // Log-in again.
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login, $user);
}
```